# Populate Date Column in Access with dates from 1980-01-01 to today with sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access Table which is named dates and has one single column named Date ( formatted as date ). I would need to have the dates from 1980-01-01 up until today incremented by 1 day at a time in the column. 1980-01-01 would be at the first row.

How can this be done with a sql query?

Comment: What is the datatype for the column?

Comment: Datatype is Date ( I have putted Date as the column name also )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add those dates with Access SQL if you have a suitable table of numbers.

```sql
INSERT INTO dates ([Date])
SELECT CDate(n.the_number)
FROM tblNumbers AS n
WHERE n.the_number BETWEEN 29221 AND 42037;
```

Or start from 1 in *tblNumbers* and add an offset ...

```sql
INSERT INTO dates ([Date])
SELECT CDate(n.the_number + 29220)
FROM tblNumbers AS n
WHERE n.the_number BETWEEN 1 AND 12817;
```

But if you don't have a suitable numbers table, you would need to create one and populate it.  And that is similar to the problem you started with, only loading plain numbers instead of dates.

The original task is simple enough that I would use a throwaway VBA procedure instead of Access SQL.  This one took less than 2 seconds to load my *dates* table with the required 12,817 date values:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim dte As Date
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("dates", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)
With rs
    For dte = #1/1/1980# To Date
        .AddNew
        ![Date].Value = dte
        .Update
    Next
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: This solution had superior speed.

Comment: Yes, it should be faster because it doesn't require you to format the date value into a string, concatenate that string into an `INSERT` statement string, and then execute the final string.  You simply add the raw date value directly into a new row.  The *dbAppendOnly* option for `OpenRecordset` should help performance, too.

Comment: May I ask: What does the ! in the ![Date] = dte statement mean?

Comment: Sure, `!` is used to refer to a member of a collection.  For example, `[Forms]![Form1]` ... *Form1* is a member of the collection of forms which are currently open.  In this answer, `![Date]` is inside the `With rs` block, so it is essentially `rs![Date]` ... um, actually `rs![Date].Value` since `.Value` is the default property for a recordset field.  I will edit the answer to include `.Value` explicitly even though it is not required.

Comment: BTW, I strongly endorse Marek's advice to avoid [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) as database object names.  Enclosing *Date* in square brackets, `[Date]`, avoids confusing the db engine about which you mean, but it's best to avoid reserved words in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Last question ^^ : The method .addnew is before the ![Date].value, if I understand it correctly, the recordset creates an empty field, then assigns the empty field to the same value as the dte variable?

Comment: `.AddNew` adds a new row to the recordset.  Then `![Date].Value = dte` loads the current value of the *dte* variable into the `[Date]` field of that new row.  Finally, `.Update` saves the new row into the source table.

Answer (score 2):

First, rename your column to something else then `Date`, as it is a reserved word and it would cause you much trouble. In my example I named the column `DateField`.

I assume when you said sql query, you meant access sql, in which case it cannot be done, as access sql doesn't support cycles.

However, you can do it easily by VBA, please see below:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim myDateString As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    myDate = #1/1/1980#

    Do While myDate < Now
        myDateString = Format(myDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO DateTable (DateField) VALUES(#" & myDate & "#)"

        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

        myDate = myDate + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: PS: I always convert the date to string before passing it to query to prevent locale errors. The SQL format (yyyy-mm-ss) is safest.

Comment: Ahh thank you! May I ask: What errors may the Date column name cause? I know it's not recommended, but it's a much more intuitive name and until now haven't caused any errors

Comment: Glad to have helped! The problem is that Date is also a name of a function, Date(), and conflicts could easily arise when the SQL engine would not be able to decide whether you want to select a column or call a function. Just search for "access reserved words" to see more examples.